# ReactJS and Capybara: adding a Google Maps component breaks feature specs

Tags: google-maps-api-3, rspec, reactjs, capybara, poltergeist

I have a Rails app with all the front end rendered by React. I am using Rspec with Capybara and Poltergeist for testing. Repo [here](https://github.com/janklimo/makersofbangkok).

As soon as I add my [map component](https://github.com/janklimo/makersofbangkok/blob/master/app/webpack_javascripts/makersofbangkok/components/home/events/map.jsx) (I am using [google-map-react](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react) for this), React doesn't render anything in test environment and this breaks all feature specs (including those which do not test pages with map in it).

[image]

However, everything works perfectly in the browser. As there are no errors, this is quite puzzling.

Many thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling poltergeist errors in tests, I found out the problem was this:

[image]

Version `0.10.3` of `google-map-react` has `es6-promise` dependecy, so upgrading to the latest version fixed the issue.